# Where can I find a trained neural network data to play with?

Tags: neural-network, dataset, training

This is the trained neural network for the XOR operator:

[image]

Can I find something like a trained network for recognizing hand writing digits somewhere on the internet? Is there an "official format" for trained neural networks?

Comment: Yes there is popular ("official format") for trained neural network model, for example tensorflow use .pb file to store the model weights and biases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the super popular and classical MINIST? Tensorflow has a nice tutorial:

> https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners

Just follow the instructions!

Answer (score 1):

There are many pre-trained models but for more complicated task, I recommend to check out [Caffe Model Zoo](https://github.com/caffe2/caffe2/wiki/Model-Zoo).